# Keflavik International Airport to Selfoss

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, iceland, reykjavik, kef

I will arrive in Keflavik International Airport Iceland and I have to meet with my friend traveler at Selfoss.

I am looking for bus timetables but I can't find info.
Does anyone has info about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to leave bus 55 at Fjordur.
To get to Mjoddin you can take bus nr. 21
When you get to Mjoddin you change to bus nr. 51.

Less of a hassle but probably much more expensive is this https://www.re.is/flybus-south

Best of luck and safe travel.

Comment: looking into those options, the plane arrive at 4:40pm in sunday

Comment: finally flybus wasn't expensive, was my best option (because sunday).

Answer (score 9):

You have to catch Bus 55 to Reykjavik (you can catch the more expensive  Flybus and Greyline shuttles if you want), from Reykjavik you can catch buses 51 to Selfoss.

The Reykjavík bus system, Strætó, runs buses to Selfoss. The route is number 51 and buses leave from Mjódd interchange station in Reykjavík, goes through Hveragerði and terminates at Fossnesti in Selfoss. One ride between Reykjavík and Selfoss costs 1,400 kr. and buses leave close to once every hour during weekdays, less frequently on weekends.

https://www.straeto.is/en/

Schedules are here:

https://www.straeto.is/en/timatoflur

Comment: Does Bus 55 stop at Mjódd, or can Flybus or Greyline drop people off there?

Comment: looking into those options, the plane arrive at 4:40pm in sunday